# Flyweight Pattern : UnsharedConcreteFlyweight

Tags: design-patterns, liskov-substitution-principle, flyweight-pattern

Here is the flyweight pattern structural diagram:

[image]

Here you see UnsharedConcreteFlyweight which GoF explains:

> UnsharedConcreteFlyweight : 
>   Not all Flyweight subclasses need to be shared. The Flyweight
>   interface enables sharing; it doesn't enforce it. It's common for
>   UnsharedConcreteFlyweight objects to have ConcreteFlyweight objects as
>   children at some level in the flyweight object structure (as the Row
>   and Column classes have).

Here as much as I understand `Operation` takes `in extrinsicState` as argument, but it will not use it at all, as far as it has `allState` as member data.

Is it a good design? To take arguments you don't use, and if you will use, then you will have data duplication. This may even be Liskov Substitution Principle violation?

Comment: I doubt, you rarely find a pattern which conforms with all the SOLID principles for all the use cases. Isn't it? 'Convenience' plays a key-role here. If we rigidly follow some principle with immense hard-work, but only achieve all-most nothing rather than just happiness of following it, definitely makes no sense. :))

Answer (score 0):

It is still good! The Liskov Substitution Principle (LSP) is all about *Design By Contract*. As long as the `UnsharedConcreteFlyweight.Operation` satisfies the contract of `Flyweight.Operation`, no problem!

Ignoring input parameters (extrinsic state in this case) is just an indication of LSP violation, not always.